# PHP script works fine only on localhost

Tags: json, curl

I'm using this script for parsing an URL that contain a JSON structure. Works fine on localhost (XAMPP) but doesn't work on server side. Anyone have some suggestion about this? I can't find any solutions...

EDIT: The problem is the HOSTING of my website where the script run. It allow communication only on port 80 and 443. There are solutions?

```
<?php
function session_type($type) {
switch ($type) {
    case 0:
        return "Booking";
    break;
    case 1:
        return "Pratica";
    break;
    case 2:
        return "Qualifica";
    break;
    case 3:
        return "Gara";
    break;
    default:
        return "Error";
    break;
  }
}
$server = "http://95.141.37.33:8098/INFO";
$ch = curl_init($server);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$sjson = json_decode($output, true);

echo 'Current Track: ' . $sjson['track'] . '<br />';
echo 'Name: '. $sjson['name'] . '<br />';
echo 'Utenti Online: '. $sjson['clients'] . '<br />';
foreach ($sjson['cars'] as $key=>$value)
{
echo "Auto:". $value ."<br />";
};
echo 'Port: '. $sjson['port'] . '<br />';
echo 'Sessione: ' . session_type($sjson['session']) . '<br />';
echo 'Timeleft: '. $sjson['timeleft'] . '<br />';

$users = "http://95.141.37.33:8098/JSON|";
$ch = curl_init($users);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$output_user = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


$ujson = json_decode($output_user, true);

echo 'Racers: <br />';
foreach ($ujson as $key => $jsons) {
    foreach ($jsons as $key => $value) {
        echo $value['DriverName'] . '<br />';
   }
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can tunnel the traffic to another server that takes the packets in on port 80 and then sends the packet to the correct location on the correct port.

Comment: Thank you Smith for the reply, can you give me an example?

Comment: Google search or something for tunneling services etc...